# Unit-test functions that conform xml elements according to a xsd schema

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, xsd, pytest

Say, for simplicity, we have three elements "a", "b" and "c" defined in a xsd where:

- "a" and "b" are childs of "c",
- Element "c" can be also child of itself,
- Elements "a" and "b" does not have childs.

I wrote a function that "scan" a xml and if it detects wrong elements, it will try - if possible - to conform them according to the xsd. The main piece of code :

```py
# conformity.py

from lxml.etree import Element

def conform_element_a(root: Element) -> Element | None:
   # If some attributes of the root as element "a" 
   # are not compliant, apply some transformations
   # to these in order to conform root.
   # If transformations are possible, return root.
   # If transformations are not possible, return None.

def conform_element_b(root: Element) -> Element | None:
   # same as before

def conform_element_c(root: Element):
   # conform child "a"
   a = root.find("a")
   if a is not None:
      a = conform_element_a(a)
      if a is None:
         root.remove(a)
   # conform child "b"
   b = root.find("b")
   if b is not None:
      b = conform_element_b(b)
      if b is None:
         root.remove(b)
   # conform child "c"
   c = root.find("c")
   if c is not None:
      c = conform_element_c(c)
```

Now, I want to test these three function. For testing `conform_element_a` and `conform_element_b`, I was thinking to use factories as fixtures, like the following for `conform_element_a`:

```py
import pytest
from lxml import etree
from mypackage.utils import tree_equality
from mypackage.conformity import conform_element_a

# Factory
@pytest.fixture
def make_element_a():
    def _make_element_a(**kwargs):
        # build an element "a"
        # according to kwargs
        return a

    return _make_element_a


class TestConformA:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("attrib_1", [...])
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("attrib_2", [...])
    def test_none_case(make_element_a, attrib_1, attrib_2):
        a = make_element_a(attrib_1, attrib_2)
        a = conform_element_a(a)
        assert a is None
    
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("attrib_1, exp1", [...])
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("attrib_2, exp2", [...])
    def test_not_none(make_element, attrib_1, attrib_2, exp1, exp2):
        a = make_element_a(attrib_1, attrib_2)
        expected = make_element_a(exp1, exp2)
        a = conform_element_a(a)
        assert tree_equality(a, expected)
```

Two questions :

1. I'm wondering it's not the good approach for testing `conform_element_a` and `conform_element_b`. Here I put two attributes for example purpose, but in reality there is more and it can quickly become verbose.
2. I don't see how to test the function `conform_element_c`. Before, there were only attributes as parameters. But now there are attributes and children ! Especially the case where "c" can be a children of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my subjective thoughts:

- From what you've shown, `make_element_a()` should just be a regular function.  There's no reason for it to be a fixture.
- Since all of your functions operate on XML elements, why not have your test parameters be XML snippets?  You could write a simple helper function to parse these snippets into elements, and that would accomodate the tests for "a", "b", and "c".
- I don't think it's a good idea to nest `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorators like that.  Doing so makes it hard to clearly associate expected inputs to expected outputs.  The only time I would do this is when some of the parameters have no bearing on the expected output, e.g. testing multiple factories that all should construct the same object.

With the above in mind, here's how I might write these tests:

```
import pytest
from mypackage.utils import elem_from_str, tree_equality
from mypackage.conformity import conform_element_a

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'given, expected', [
        (
            '<a/>',
            '<a/>',
        ), (
            '<a x=1/>',
            '<a x=2/>',
        ), (
            '<a y=1/>',
            None,
        ),
    ]
)
def test_conform_element_a(given, expected):
    given = elem_from_str(given)
    expected = elem_from_str(expected)
    conformed = conform_element_a(given)
    assert tree_equality(conformed, expected)
```

---

One drawback of encoding the test parameters using XML is that you'll probably end up with multiline XML snippets, and multiline strings really make the parameter list hard to read.  I wrote a package called [*Parametrize From File*](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that can help with this by (as the name implies) allowing you to specify parameters in an external file.  All the common config file formats (YAML, TOML, JSON) are supported, but in my opinion the best format for multiline strings is [Nested Text](https://nestedtext.org/en/latest/).

Here's how your tests might look with this approach:

```
# test_conform_element.nt
test_conform_element_c:
  -
    id: no-children
    given: <c/>
    expected: <c/>
  -
    id: child-ab
    given:
      > <c>
      >  <a/>
      >  <b/>
      > </c>
    expected:
      > <c>
      >  <a/>
      >  <b/>
      > </c>
  -
    id: child-c-recursive
    given:
      > <c>
      >  <c>
      >   <a>
      >   <b>
      >  </c>
      > </c>
    expected:
      > <c>
      >  <c>
      >   <a>
      >   <b>
      >  </c>
      > </c>
```

```py
# test_conform_element.py
import parametrize_from_file
from mypackage.utils import elem_from_str, tree_equality
from mypackage.conformity import conform_element_c

@parametrize_from_file
def test_conform_element_c(given, expected):
    given = elem_from_str(given)
    expected = elem_from_str(expected)
    conformed = conform_element_c(given)
    assert tree_equality(conformed, expected)
```

I think this makes both the test code and the test parameters much easier to read.